# Udevadm trigger is not permitted

Tags: 12.04, apt, kernel

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed, yesterday i performed an update, but the update center froze for some reason, when i tried to reboot the pc, i was unable to and i got the following error message: 
"udevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unconfigured"
I have tried to get in with a live CD, and i tried this command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

(i have 2 kernels 3.13.0-32-generic and 3.13.0-52-generic i dont know why, i even tried sudo update-initramfs -u -k 3.13.0-32-generic) 
so that did not work.

then i tried this:

```
sudo mkdir /media/newroot/
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/newroot/
sudo chroot /media/newroot/
sudo apt-get update
```

but it failed to reach all the links with

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
```

Is there anyway to fix or reinstall the kernal or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct steps:

```
sudo mkdir /media/newroot/
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/newroot/
sudo chroot /media/newroot/
dpkg --configure -a
```

and then run:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all


umount /media/newroot/
```

Then restart.

> sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu

This is not a big deal and don't care about this run since you are using live cd and Ubuntu is the default hostname in livecd while you are trying to run from chroot.

PS: you dont need sudo when you chroot

There is a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devmapper/+bug/358654) about this case