# udevadm trigger not permitted message on the screen

Tags: mount, mkdir

The solution for the problem described is given in askubuntu, I tried booting with bootable USB. The options of Install Ubuntu and try Ubuntu were displayed but I am not sure which option to choose.

- When I tried with choosing the option of Try Ubuntu and typed in command

  ```
  sudo fdisk -l
  sudo mkdir /media/newroot
  sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/newroot
  ```

  the Error message is

  ```
  mkdir: cannot create directory 'media/newroot':File exists
  ```
- when I type in `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/newroot`

  The Error message displayed is

  ```
  cant find /dev/sdb1/media/newroot
  ```

Can some one please guide me? I'm stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could tell us what are trying to do? Are you trying to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I already have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed but the above said problem has cropped up.

Answer (score 0):

- Your question as it now is not clear. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

  So basically, You have installed Ubuntu after reboot you got this error:

  > udevadm trigger not permitted

  Then you boot from USB stick and trying to recover it by following this post:

  [Udevadm trigger is not permitted](https://askubuntu.com/a/634132/26246)
- Well, the first error message:

  > mkdir: cannot create directory 'media/newroot':File exists

  comes from `mkdir /media/newroot` because you already have `/media/newroot` in place. So no need to create it.

  The second one:

  > cant find /dev/sdb1/media/newroot

  See by mistake, you missed a space between `/dev/sdb1` & `/media/newroot`
- Would you try it again, and use this command to check if it get mounted correctly:

  ```
  ls /media/newroot
  ```

  You should see your files there. If it is was ok carry on:

  ```
  sudo chroot /media/newroot/
  dpkg --configure -a
  update-initramfs -u -k all
  exit
  sudo umount /media/newroot/
  sudo reboot
  ```